# Troubleshooting ignored functions for Firebase emulator

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I'm starting my cloud function emulator according to the documentation here:

```
firebase emulators:start --only functions
```

Things look smooth for the onRequest functions:

```
i  Starting emulators: ["functions"]
⚠  Your requested "node" version "8" doesn't match your global version "10"
✔  functions: Emulator started at http://localhost:5001
i  functions: Watching "/Users/.../functions" for Cloud Functions...
i  functions: HTTP trigger initialized at http://localhost:5001/sweever-prod/us-central1/sendMailTrigger
i  functions: HTTP trigger initialized at http://localhost:5001/sweever-prod/us-central1/sitemapData
```

but falls flat when there are onTrigger functions:

```
Ignoring trigger "newUserSignedUp" because the Cloud Firestore emulator is not running.
Ignoring trigger "newItemAdded" because the Cloud Firestore emulator is not running.
Ignoring trigger "itemUpdated" because the Cloud Firestore emulator is not running.
```

What might the cause of onTrigger functions being ignored locally? I'm led to believe Firestore *can* handle these locally given the documentation's reference: "Cloud Functions emulator which can emulate the following function types: ... Cloud Firestore functions." I think the onTrigger would be a Cloud Firestore function but might be confusing the terminology.

Comment: What do you mean by "onTrigger" functions?  There aren't any onTrigger type functions that I'm aware of.  Would you like to edit the question to share the code of the functions that don't deploy?

Comment: Just like onWrite, onCreate. Functions that run when there's a trigger event: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to run the emulators for multiple products (Hosting and Firestore), you should be starting the emulator with the command:

```
firebase emulators:start
```

Right now, you are just starting the emulator for functions that don't involve Firestore.  Please refer to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator#run_the_emulator_suite) for more information.